# Inserting cell to top of uitableview causes problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is driving me nuts, I have sections in my `UITableView`, but this insertion works when I don't have sections.

Basically I'm doing:

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

I'm getting this error:

> The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (5) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (4), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 0 deleted).'

I thought it would just work, but this doesn't make sense. What can you guys make of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning different values from your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` method before and after you send the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method.

If you are creating an entirely new section in the table view, you must insert it by sending `insertSections:withRowAnimation:` message to the table view.

Comment: I'm still working on it.  What I did is I called an insert section, and  then right after that an insert row.  The issue I think is that when I call INSERT section, it UITableView will call BOTH my numberOfSections and numberOfRowsPerSection.  I would return the correct sections, but then I'd also return an incremented Row value which they didn't like.  I think I would have to increment the row AFTER I call the insert row.  That would solve it i think.

Comment: So my solution was to first determine if a section was needed, if so, insert it, but make sure I only incremented the sections in numberOfSections, but not the numberOfRowsPerSection.  Only increment the row count RIGHT BEFORE I've called insertRowsAtIndexPaths, so the numberOfRowsPerSections would return the correct rows.  I had previously thought that I can insert both section and rows one after another while updating the row and section count right before it, but each of them would call numberOfSections and numberOfRowsPerSection on it's own, that was what caused the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make a `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` call, you also need to modify the data source that backs the table with a similar addition.  This ensures that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` returns `n` before the addition and `n+1` after the addition.  Anything besides a consistent result with throw the error you described.

Comment: His error isn't about the number of rows.  It's about the number of sections.

Comment: Right you are, the inconsistency can result from any mismatch in either rows or sections.